# Composition of two function $f \circ g$, where $g$ is a piecewise.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f$ be a function defined by
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-5x}$$
for all real number $x$ with $x\le 0$ or $x\ge 5$.
Also, let $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function defined by
and
\begin{align*}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2+1, x>0 \\
x+1, x\le 0
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Find $f \circ g$.

**Attempt:**
Notice that
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x^2+1), x>0 \\
f(x+1), x\le 0
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
For $x \le 0$, we get
$$(f \circ g)(x) = \sqrt{x^2-3x-4}$$
whenever $x \le -1$ or $x \ge 4$. By the case, it must be happened if $x \le -1$.

For $x > 0$, we obtain
$$(f \circ g)(x) = \sqrt{x^4-3x^2-4}$$
whenever $x \le -2$ or $x \ge 2$. By the case, it must be happened if $x \ge 2$.

Therefore, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^2-3x-4}, x\le -1 \\
\sqrt{x^4-3x^2-4}, x \ge 2
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

Does this correct?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is $f(3)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Not defined. So?

Comment: So it is wrong to write that $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$. But that's what you wrote.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos done. So, how is it?

Comment: Yes, the statement is clear now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos okay. So, what about my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139636/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-pitik-kepit).